# Modify URL to add my custom query string is not working?

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

just want to add my custom query params before Cef sending request, here is my code:

```
public class CustomResourceRequestHandler : ResourceRequestHandler
{
    protected override CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        request.Url = request.Url + "?name=foo";

        return CefReturnValue.Continue;
    }
}
```

the browser showed a empty page, what is the correct way to add my query params?

Comment: https://survey.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SID=SV_1234?state=CA&city=LA

Comment: @GoodSamaritan  thks, but the request is about CEF.

Comment: Beware this custom handler works for every asset for the page requested (images css scripts etc.) Adding query string may cause resources fail to load. And Url might have **?** already, you should check its existence .

Comment: Try only modifying the request if the query string parameter doesn't already exist.

Comment: @amaitland thks, I got it.